# Multiple types in a list?

Tags: scala

**Rephrasing of my questions:**

I am writing a program that implements a data mining algorithm. In this program I want to save the input data which is supposed to be minded. Imagine the input data to be a table with rows and columns. Each row is going to be represented by an instance of my Scala class (the one in question). The columns of the input data can be of different type (Integer, Double, String, whatnot) and which type will change depending on the input data. I need a way to store a row inside my Scala class instance. Thus I need an ordered collection (like a special List) that can hold (many) different types as elements and it must be possible that the type is only determined at runtime. How can I do this? A Vector or a List require that all elements are supposed to be of the same type. A Tuple can hold different types (which can be determined at runtime if I am not mistaken), but only up to 22 elements which is too few.

Bonus (not sure if I am asking too much now):

- I would also like to have the rows' columns to be named and excess-able by name. However, I thinkg this problem can easily be solved by using two lists. (Altough, I just read about this issue somewhere - but I forgot where - and think this was solved more elegantly.)
- It might be good to have my collection to be random access (so "Vector" rather than "List").
- Having linear algebra (matrix multiplication etc.) capabilities would be nice.
- Even more bonus: If I could save matrices.

---

**Old phrasing of my question:**

I would like to have something like a data.frame as we know it from R in Scala, but I am only going to need one row. This row is going to be a member in a class. The reason for this construct is that I want methods related to each row to be close to the data itself. Each data row is also supposed to have meta data about itself and it will be possible to give functions so that different rows will be manipulated differently. However I need to save rows somehow within the class. A List or Vector comes to mind, but they only allow to be all Integer, String, etc. - but as we know from data.frame, different columns (here elements in Vector or List) can be of different type. I also would like to save the name of each column to be able to access the row values by column name. That seems the smallest issue though. I hope it is clear what I mean. How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you give an example? I really don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @wheaties: Rephrased my question. Hope that helps.

Comment: What does "the type is only determined at runtime" mean? Types exist for compile time validation; it doesn't make sense to get type info at runtime because it's useless. Doubly so because erasure.

Comment: @HTNW: What I mean: The input data could be a String, but could also be numeric value (e.g. Integer or Double). But it still needs to be possible to save this input data in my scala object. I am not sure how to do that. I might use case classes and pattern matching for the processing.

Comment: @wheaties: Why did you delete your answer? As far as I remember it was a step in the right direction for me.

Comment: @make42 I generally delete answers that sir at -1 for 1 day or more. If the community thinks they're bad or unhelpful, I don't want them around.

Comment: @wheaties: I understand. Luckily I saved the link to shapeless. What were the other links?

Comment: @Make42 Coproduct is also a shapeless entity.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames in R are heterogenous lists of homogeneous column vectors:

```
> df <- data.frame(c1=c(r1=1,r2=2), c2=c('a', 'b')); df
   c1 c2
r1  1  a
r2  2  b
```

You *could* think of each row as a heterogeneous list of scalar values:

```
> as.list(df['r1',])
$c1
[1] 1

$c2
[1] a
```

An analogous implementation in scala would be a tuple of lists:

```
scala> val df = (List(1, 2), List('a', 'b'))
df: (List[Int], List[Char]) = (List(1, 2),List(a, b))
```

Each row could then just be a tuple:

```
scala> val r1 = (1, 'a')
r1: (Int, Char) = (1,a)
```

If you want to name all your variables, another possibility is a case class:

```
scala> case class Row (col1:Int, col2:Char)
defined class Row

scala> val r1 = Row(col1=1, col2='a')
r1: Row = Row(1,a)
```

Hope that helps bridge the R to scala divide.

Comment: Very close. Can Tuple be filled with arbitrary types at runtime? Tuple can only hold up to 22 values... that's an issue. I rephrased my question. Hope that helps.